# Skip iterations in for loops

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, iteration

How can improve this algorithm in order to use a dynamic validation source?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] exclude = {1, 4, 7};

    for(int i= 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        if(i != 1 || i != 4 || i != 7);
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Meaning, I want to instead of the `if` inside the `for` loop, I want to receive a list and validate the content of must-exclude elements, maybe something like:

```
        if(Arrays.asList(exclude).contains(i))
```

Just for the sake of knowing how to do it.   I feel like it might potentially be useful in the future.  Basically I want to skip certain iterations in a loop using an array.

How

Comment: What's the question?  Does that not work?

Comment: Fix the indentation on your first sample. It makes no sense as written - correct indentation would make this apparent. Anyway, there are often many ways to do something. If you just need a "contains", however, consider a Set. Not that it makes a difference here, as it's a trivial n and small S. The `asList` each loop is also particular "wasteful" but, again, it doesn't matter here.

Comment: No it does not work as I have it written.  It prints all numbers 0-9.

Comment: @pst, I must have accidentally deleted the newline, making the formatting kind of weird in the original example.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call:

```
Arrays.asList(exclude)
```

Actually it creates a List, which is not what you want. If you declared you exclude array as an array of Integer, it would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer[] exclude = {1, 4, 7};

    for(int i= 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
       if(!Arrays.asList(exclude).contains(i))
       {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
    }
}
```

The thing is, you were providing an `int[]` to this Arrays.asList. The compiler has to decide if it should interpret the generic parameter T as int or as int[]. But it can not chose `int` because you can not have a integral type as a generic type. It could chose Integer, but it would mean a conversion, and `int[]` is therefore not direct. So T is `int[]` and it creates a `List<int[]>` with only the array you provided as element. And no integer is equals to that array as a whole of course. That is why all integers are printed.

Comment: Thanks, this works (after removing the i++ in the if statement)  However, I'm curious.  What is the difference between Interger[] and Int[]?

Comment: Would there be a more efficient way to do this as well?  Thanks, sorry for all the questions.  I'm learning!

Comment: Well, you could have created a list before the loop itself like this: `List<Integer> exclude = Arrays.asList(1,4,7);`. I don't see a better method.

Comment: I just read your edit.  Thank you, it was helpful.    However, the i++ in the if statement increments i an additional time.   I think it should be removed to function correctly.

Comment: You know that unless the compiler is _very_ clever (as it certainly is _not_ in Android and probably in the Sun JITC as well), this code causes the array to be converted to an ArrayList 10 times, then it searches in linear time.  If there are many iterations, you should build the ArrayList one time.  If there are many exclusions, you should build a HashSet instead.  The garbage created by gratuitous conversions like this tends to be okay when a program is new and customers are few and later cause nasty problems when it's old and the customer base has grown.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you've already got it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] exclude = {1, 4, 7};

    for(int i= 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
       if(Arrays.asList(exclude).contains(i))
       {
           i++;
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either.  It prints 0-9 without excluding the numbers in the array.